# Cannot GET Error after deployment on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, deployment

I have tried several times to deploy my NodeJs app to Heroku for days but I keep getting this error: "Cannot GET /" after deployment. At this point, I will gladly appreciate the help.

Here is my server:
[Server.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AahJa.png)

My routes:
[routes file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOUvg.png)

Heroku logs[Heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbsIi.png)

My file directory looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va3bG.png)

Comment: Did you ever test on your own machine before using Heroku?

Comment: First of all, is the server working okay locally? If you go to localhost:3000 you can see your index page?

Comment: Absolutely, use whichever terminal you like , in the right directory, run node Server.js

Comment: Yes, the server is working well on my local machine but the moment I deploy I get the error.

Comment: It is probably better to give full copy of your serverjs and routers file

Comment: Thanks Isaac. I figured out the issue. I needed  app.use('/', require('./routes/members')); // instead of app.use('/mychurch', require('./routes/members')); //home route. Thank you for your help and time.